# How to generate barcode in qt?

Tags: qt, barcode, barcode-printing

i have to develop application that create a paint object. and user can add different items such as shape , image , date ... . one of that items is barcode such as this image :
[barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SK6G.png)

is exist a library for generate unique barcode? and how to draw it in Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Qt library named "Prison" which can generate bar codes and QR codes
https://quickgit.kde.org/?p=prison.git

Comment: Thank you. @kevinKrammer

Comment: can you help how to use it? when build prison project , compile error occured that say prison_export.h file not exist in project. how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, haven't used it myself yet. That file should have been generated at configure time though. Did you get any errors at the cmake step?

Comment: hi @mohamadjalali, do you fixed your compile error?...I´m starting to study this library and your information will be helpfull.

Comment: @LuisGama unfortunately no, I use zint library.